# How to make text wrap in ionic2?

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 to build an app.

I need to display a list of salad. I used `<ion-list>` and `<ion-item>` to build it. The problem is the items only can display in one line.
shown in the following image:
[image]

**The CODE**

```
    <ion-list>
    <div class='title'>ALL SANDWICHES</div>
    <div text-wrap class='subtitle'>SERVED ON ARBUTUS SOURDOUGH BREAD
WHOLEMEAL SOURDOUGH & GLUTEN FREE ARE AVAILABLE</div>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let test of tests" class='item item-text-wrap'>
            <!-- <div>{{test.id}}</div> -->
            <div class='name' >{{test.name}} </div>
            <div class='info'>{{test.info}} </div>
            <div>€ {{test.price}}</div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

**The CSS**

```
div.name{
    font-weight: bold;
}
div.info{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

It seems both code `class='item item-text-wrap'` and css `text-align: justify;` can't work.

**THE QUESTION**
Is it possible to dispaly content in multiple lines?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Because you use class for editing text. So it's not working. In Ionic 2 , it has attribute 'text-wrap' use within ion-item tag.

```
  <ion-list>
     <div class='title'>ALL SANDWICHES</div>
     <div text-wrap class='subtitle'>SERVED ON ARBUTUS SOURDOUGH BREAD
       WHOLEMEAL SOURDOUGH & GLUTEN FREE ARE AVAILABLE</div>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let test of tests" text-wrap>
        <!-- <div>{{test.id}}</div> -->
        <div class='name' >{{test.name}} </div>
        <div class='info'>{{test.info}} </div>
        <div>€ {{test.price}}</div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Cheer!

Answer (score 1):

If you put `text-wrap` (as an attribute, not as a class) in the `ion-list`, all items in that list will have the text-wrap effect applied. This way you don't need to put the text-wrap directive in all items and making your app slightly optimized.

```
<ion-list text-wrap> <!-- Add text-wrap at this level -->
    <div class='title'>ALL SANDWICHES</div>
    <div class='subtitle'>SERVED ON ARBUTUS SOURDOUGH BREAD WHOLEMEAL SOURDOUGH & GLUTEN FREE ARE AVAILABLE</div>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let test of tests" class='item item-text-wrap'>
            <!-- <div>{{test.id}}</div> -->
            <div class='name' >{{test.name}} </div>
            <div class='info'>{{test.info}} </div>
            <div>€ {{test.price}}</div>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```